# Error when install scipy and seaborn on jupyter notebook

Tags: scipy, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, apple-m1

I'm using Macbook Pro(apple m1), and I've installed scipy and seaborn on my laptop with no problem. Now I'm trying to install scipy and seaborn on Jupyter Notebook(NumPy, pandas, and matplotlib installed on jupyter with no problems), but I'm getting error messages as the screenshot below. It seems like a problem about openblas, BLAS & LAPACK on my Jupiter notebook environment. Please help. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGBSq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s3C3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIv4.png)

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If you are using anaconda, do not use pip to install packages that exist within the conda ecosystem. use `conda install package`. Only use pip if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because pip and conda do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found this answer from another post, it worked.

```
pip install --pre -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple scipy
```